# Using logical OR in IF condition of an MySQL query to check for NoneType or float

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-python

I am trying to write an SQL query with an IF condition as follows -

```
IF (field_name1=0.0,0,ROUND(field_name1, 2)) as new_name,
```

When the query is run and the value of `new_name` is being consumed as `metric` in -

```
percentage_diffs = df_filtered[metric].pct_change().round(5) * 100
```

I am getting the following error -

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'float'
```

How do I check if the value of `field_name1` is either `0.0` OR `NoneType`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a OR clauue

> ```
> CREATE tABLE tab1 (field_name1 DOUBLE)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES (NULL),(0.0)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
> IF ((field_name1 IS NULL OR field_name1=0.0),0,ROUND(field_name1, 2)) as new_name FROM tab1
> ```
>
> ```
> | new_name |
> | -------: |
> |        0 |
> |        0 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=08fcfe5a99c73caa108a225fa7c97546)*